# Override counsel-yank-pop binding with use-package

Tags: key-bindings, use-package, counsel

I would like to use the classic emacs `yank-pop` instead of counsel mode's `counsel-yank-pop` which is linked to `M-y`. I've tried unbinding and rebinding it, but it does not seem to work.

I setup counsel using the following code:

```
(use-package counsel
  :bind (("C-x C-f" . counsel-find-file)
         ("C-c s"   . counsel-recentf)
         ("C-c C-s" . counsel-locate)
         ("C-c S"   . counsel-ack)
         :map minibuffer-local-map
         ("C-r" . counsel-minibuffer-history))
  :custom
  (counsel-linux-app-format-function #'counsel-linux-app-format-function-name-only)
  :config
  (counsel-mode 1))
```

At this point, if I describe-variable `counsel-mode-map`, I can see that the binding `M-y      counsel-yank-pop` exists. Also, if I run `helpful-key` I can see the same.  However, I am unable to change the binding to `yank-pop`. I've tried:

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "M-y"))
(local-unset-key (kbd "M-y"))
(unbind-key "M-y" counsel-mode-map)
```

However, as soon as I try to rebind to `yank-pop` the binding goes back to `counsel-yank-pop`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-y") 'yank-pop)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the answer might be to remove enable `counsel-mode` in `use-package` and set the keybinding globally.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-y") 'yank-pop)

(use-package counsel
  :bind (("C-x C-f" . counsel-find-file)
         ("C-c s"   . counsel-recentf)
         ("C-c C-s" . counsel-locate)
         ("C-c S"   . counsel-ack)
         :map minibuffer-local-map
         ("C-r" . counsel-minibuffer-history))
  :custom
  (counsel-linux-app-format-function #'counsel-linux-app-format-function-name-only))
```

Comment: FYI - You can accept your answer, if you like.

Comment: Not yet :/ 23 more hours to go.